# Display the dialogue box after checking condition

Tags: primefaces

I am checking whether a mail is valid by using regular expressions, on  the dialogue box. And according to the result I want  the dialogue box to close or stay open, but it always closes no matter the mail address is valid or not. My bean function returns correct result(myBean.isValid), I debugged it. What can be the problem?

Here is my code:

```
<p:commandButton value="Save"
   actionListener="#{myBean.saveStg}"
   update="growl,stg_panel,stg" 
   oncomplete="if(myBean.isValid){confirmation.hide()}else{confirmation.show()}" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following changes to you code:

add `mybutton` to update attribute and change `{#myBean.isValid}` into `#{myBean.isValid}` and you better change `oncomplete` into `onsuccess`

```
<p:commandButton id="mybutton" value="Save"
   actionListener="#{myBean.saveStg}"
   update="growl,stg_panel,stg,mybutton" 
   onsuccess="if(#{myBean.isValid}){confirmation.hide()}else{confirmation.show()}" />
```

b.t.w here an additional simple working example :

```
  <h:body>
    <h:form prependId="false">

     <h:panelGrid>  
        <p:commandButton id="basic" update="basic" value="Basic"
         actionListener="#{myBean.lalala}" 
         onsuccess="if(#{myBean.evenNumber}){dlg1.show();}else{dlg1.hide();}"/>
    </h:panelGrid>  

    <p:dialog id="basicDialog" header="Basic Dialog" widgetVar="dlg1">  
        <h:outputText value="Resistance to PrimeFaces is futile!" />  
    </p:dialog>  
    </h:form>
  </h:body>
```

bean code

.
.
.

```
boolean evenNumber;

public boolean isEvenNumber() {
    return evenNumber;
}

public void setEvenNumber(boolean evenNumber) {
    this.evenNumber = evenNumber;
}


public void lalala(ActionEvent actionEvent) {  
    evenNumber = !evenNumber;
}
```

.
.
.

Comment: It is interesting because nothing changes... It still closes the dialogue box no matter what.

Comment: Thank you but my problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in the Primefaces showcase ([Login Demo](http://web.archive.org/web/20130727013414/http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogLogin.jsf)) whitch exactly does what you want. You can adapt it.

Comment: I have looked there too, but may be the problem is not on this part of the code it is a really big project. Now I am doing this by refreshing the page, but of course it is not a absolute solution. If I solve the problem I will write here. Thank you for your interests.

Comment: @DrewJordan You are right. Thank you very much for this comment. Maybe some day I will delete my post..

Answer (score -1):

Sorry i just noticed that this question was asked way back in 2012. So anyone else looking for an answer might find this useful.
You can hide your dialog box from the actionListener method. All you need to do is call 
`RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("dlg1.hide()");`
when the mail is valid. Thanks !